# How can I modify finder left bar icons?

Tags: finder, macos

For example take this attached picture in your consideration. Here in this case, I want ditto "Music" type icon to replicate for folder type icon.

[image]

I have tried CandyBar app. It does change the folder icons but when I add folder which in this case is "Music to the sidebar then it appear like normal folder as shown in the picture, provided that this Music folder come from another partition or drive wherein I have kept my complete music library.

Comment: @grgarside question updated..candybar doesn't apply here in this case.